# How to set a Video Background in ASP .NetCore MVC Web Application

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

Currently, I am working on a ASP .NetCore project to make a web application. I face trouble in setting a video background for the entire application. There are plenty of methods to set a video background for ordinary Html/CSS projects but I was unable to find a reliable method to set up a video background for a ASP.net core MVC web application.

**Project Details:**

1. **Framework**: ASP .NetCore MVC web application
2. **Target Framework**: net 5.0

This is my project structure:[The folder structure of the MVC web app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMsrN.png)

I was in a hurry to find a way to do this. I am sorry if the information provided by me are not sufficient. Yes, I have tried using simple available methods such as,

- Using video tag in _layout.cshtml file as follows.

HTML code:

```
    <div class="fullscreen-bg">
      <video loop muted autoplay poster="images/background.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
                <source src="../../wwwroot/video/background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.fullscreen-bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}
        
.fullscreen-bg__video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The video file is saved in images folder of wwwroot folder. It is a mp4 file.

I have tried several codes similar to above code, but it does not work in ASP.NETcore web app.

Comment: Hello. I'm not sure what ur problem seems to be. Where did you get, what did you use and what was the result or error you got?  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=video+as+site+background

Comment: @Shizma What are you found error actually? and what actually want to do in your application.

Comment: Do you mean that the video is not shown on the view, or it doesn't play, even the wrong style?

Comment: Sir, it does not play on the view as a background video. In some attempts it does show as a video playing in a media player. but it does not view as a background video.

Comment: Have you transcoded this mp4 before using it?

Comment: yes sir, I converted the file to mp4 again using format factory also. And I used few more mp4 videos instead of using same one. but no result. Sir, I am much obliged if you can provide me any other alternative solution also. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: Can you give some window captures(inlude Player button)? The video could not be loaded here.

Comment: Any errors in browser console?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is the path problem, wwwroot is a web root path when you run it. So the path need to be changed as:

```
<source src="~/video/background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

Edit:

It is possible that browser has compatibility issues with the transcoded video. You can also use [videojs](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/).

```
<div>
<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="1296" height="728"
       poster="video/cover.png" data-setup="{}">

    <source src="~/images/1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
        supports HTML5 video
    </p>
</video>
</div>
@section Scripts{
  <link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video.min.js"></script>
  @*If you'd like to support IE8*@
  @*<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"> </script>*@
<script>
    var my_video = videojs('my-video');
    videojs('my-video').ready(function () {
        var myvideo = this;
        myvideo.play();
    });
</script>
}
```

Comment: Sir, thank you very much for your answer. but it did not work. This works very well in ordinary html/css projects but unfortunately these approaches are not working in asp.net core projects. Again thank you very much for your help, sir.

Comment: Can you give some captures about it? Only the player status.

Comment: You can try this video.js, it could help browser to parse the video.

Comment: @ShizmaShaheez, you're welcome, can this help you?

Comment: Yes Sir. I learned a lot from the posts you put to my question. But I found below answer works as I hoped. In your method also video worked, but the background was not setup properly. I think I should make few more css changes to optimize it. but below answer works perfectly in my project. I had nothing to do much. Sir with all due respect thank you very much for your genuine support. I am much obliged for your help at such a short notice. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem, once. This could be solved by few codes added to the _layout.cshtml. Following is the method I followed to solve the issue. I hope this might help you to solve your issue, too.

I made the following changes in the **_layout.cshtml** file.

1. In _layout.cshtml you can find the following code snippet:

   ```
   <div class="container">
      <main role="main" class="pb-3">
         @RenderBody()
      </main>
   </div>
   ```
2. Modify it as follows:

   ```
     <div class="container embed-responsive">
        <main role="main">
           <div>
              <video autoplay muted loop poster="">
                  <source src="" data-src="https://webtests.blob.core.windows.net/samplevideo/background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              </video>
              <div class="container">
                  @RenderBody()
              </div>
           </div>
        </main>
     </div>
   ```
3. In the 'body' tag, add the bootstrap classes 'jumbotron' and 'jumbotron-fluid' as follows.

   `<body class="jumbotron-fluid jumbotron">`
4. In the 'nav' tag, add the bootstrap class 'fixed-top' as follows (otherwise navbar is hidden under the layers and not clickable):

   `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3 fixed-top">`
5. Now, after the `</html>` tag at the end, add the following script.

   ```
   <script>
       function backgroundVideo() {

          $("video source").each(function () {
             var sourceFile = $(this).attr("data-src");
             $(this).attr("src", sourceFile);
             var video = this.parentElement;
             video.load();
          });

       }
       window.onload = backgroundVideo;
   </script>
   ```
6. Next modify the bootstrap classes as follows. You may change the properties of the classes until the desired output is obtained.

   ```
   <style>
     .jumbotron {
        background-color: #454545;
      }

     .jumbotron .hero-section {
         position: fixed;
         z-index: 1;
         top: 0;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         object-fit: cover;
         opacity: 0.6;
         background: black;
      }

     .jumbotron .container {
         z-index: 2;
         position: relative;
      }  
   </style>
   ```

**If you may wonder how I get the 'data-src' URL for the video. It is very easy. Follow the steps below.**

1. Create an Azure account for free. (you can use your university mail/GitHub student package or just use the credit card number)
2. Search for 'Azure blob storage' and create a 'container' with public access enabled. (This can be done when creating the container)
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KE7GV.png)
3. Next upload the video file to blob storage and get the URL. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBFEM.png)
4. Now you can use that URL directly in the project.
5. You can further decrease the video file size using this online converter without affecting the quality: https://www.freeconvert.com/video-compressor

You can get the added benefit that your project size becomes less since the heavy media files are stored in the cloud.
This solved my problem. I hope you may use it wisely. Please feel free to suggest more. I am also learning and highly value your opinion.

Comment: Sir, your code is working as I need. And, It is very clear explanation. Your media file (water drop falling to water) is displayed on my project as I intended. So, if I want to put my own video, I have to create the Azure account. Isn't it Sir?

Comment: @ShizmaShaheez Yes, you can create Azure blob storage or Google cloud storage (but for google cloud you have to use a credit card). I noticed you are a student. So, by using the Github student package you can easily make Azure blob storage save your file in a public container, and get the URL. (no coding there at all )

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and clear explanation, Sir. My project is now working perfectly. I created the Azure blob storage as you mentioned and got public URL too.